# free(): invalid pointer aborted core dumped

Tags: c, gdb

To start off, here is The  function which creates my problem :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int Q(int m, int n, int *k, int **c){
int i,j,temp,**dp;
dp = malloc(n * sizeof(int *));
if (dp == NULL)
return -1;
for (i=0 ; i < n ; i++) {
*(dp+i) = malloc(m+1 * sizeof(int));
if (*(dp+i) == NULL)
return -1; }


for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
    for(j=0;j<m+1;j++){
     dp[i][j]=0;
    }
}


for (i=0 ; i < n ; i++){
free(*(dp+i));}
free(dp);
return 0;
}
```

at the end of the program, i get this error: `free(): invalid pointer aborted core dumped`
however, i cannot comprehend why this  issue happens when i use my free.

Comment: Please edit your question and fix the indention.

Answer (score 7):

`malloc(m+1 * sizeof(int))` is wrong. Multiplication is done before addition, so this means "allocate `m` bytes plus `sizeof(int)` bytes", not "allocate `m+1` elements of `int`" as expected.

It should be `malloc((m+1) * sizeof(int))`.

Comment: Nice catch, however that seems to not solve my problem in its entirety.

Comment: @DavidBrawl [The fixed program works](https://wandbox.org/permlink/aRb1UsYPnzPL7w1Y).

Comment: My fault, it seems i was compiling the wrong program.Seems like today is not my day, is it?